# add purchase order to vendor bill

Tags: soap, export, netsuite, purchase-order

I using soap api to export vendor bills to NetSuite that works, but I want to add to the "Related Records" ->  "Purchase Orders" in the table of the button of the vendor bill the PO, how do I do this?

Thanks for any help